# Trying to hide/show a div however .slideToggle() is applying to all divs on page - Advanced Custom Fields Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, advanced-custom-fields, slidetoggle

I have a hidden div that I want to show on a button press however because the ACF repeater is repeating the id it's opening all the hidden divs at once.

```
//This is inside a repeater field causing the #buy to repeat
    <button id="button">
       <img src="images/right-arrow.png" width="35" class="button__icon">
    </button>
    </div>
    <div id="buy" style="display:none" class="tour-event__wrapper--hidden tour-event__wrapper--hidden-bottom">
      <div class="widget-containter">
        <?php the_sub_field('eventbrite_widget'); ?>
      </div>
    </div>


// JQuery 
$('button').click(function () {
  $( "#buy" ).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

I think I need to find #buy using .find() or .next() however I haven't had much luck using those.

Comment: How does the repeater code look like? You have to be able to uniquely identify each iteration of the repeater and append the index to the id (so it will look like `id="buy001"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to get unique IDs on an ACF repeater, which should solve your problem:

```
<?php if(get_field('repeater_field_name')): $i = 0; ?>
<ul>
<?php while(has_sub_field('repeater_field_name')): $i++; ?>
    <li class="section-<?php echo $i; ?>">
        <button id="button<?php echo $i; ?>">
            <img src="images/right-arrow.png" width="35" class="button__icon">
        </button>
        <div id="buy<?php echo $i; ?>" style="display:none" class="tour-event__wrapper--hidden tour-event__wrapper--hidden-bottom">
            <div class="widget-containter">
            <?php the_sub_field('eventbrite_widget'); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

[Source](https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/unique-id-for-repeater-field/)

Your jQuery snippet would then be

```
$('[id^=button]').click(function(evt) {
    var buyId = evt.target.id.replace("button","buy");
    $("#"+buyId).slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
$('#button').click(function (event) {
  var button = $(event.currentTarget)
  button.parent().find("#buy").slideToggle("slow")
});
```

But IDs must be unique. I recommend, selecting based on class.

Also the code above is really fragile and rather just a hack. If your HTML structure changes, this will not work anymore.

Ideally you have to be able to uniquely identify each iteration of the repeater and append the index to the id (so it will look like id="buy001"